# Scripts running multiple times on button click

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a python GUI script with 4 buttons that call 4 relevant external scripts. On the click of each button, each relevant external script is run and it creates a separate csv file for each with data in them. The problem is that when I press the buttons on the GUI, it seems to run the corresponding scripts more than once, therby generating double the data in each csv. I do not want this, I only want the script to run once upon click to generate the data once. What should I do to stop the script from calling multiple times on the button click?

```
# Main Class that holds User Interface Objects
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    # Function for Opening Report Viewer Window From Main Window by clicking View Reports button
    def openReportViewer(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_reportViewerWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()



    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(834, 428)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        # Sim Card Button
        self.simCardButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.simCardButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 200, 211, 30))
        self.simCardButton.setToolTip("Select to parse sim card data")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.simCardButton.setFont(font)
        self.simCardButton.setObjectName("simCardButton")

        # Call Logs Button
        self.callLogButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.callLogButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 300, 211, 30))
        self.callLogButton.setToolTip("Select to parse call log data")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.callLogButton.setFont(font)
        self.callLogButton.setObjectName("callLogButton")

        # SMS Button
        self.smsButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.smsButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 250, 211, 30))
        self.smsButton.setToolTip("Select to parse sms data")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.smsButton.setFont(font)
        self.smsButton.setObjectName("smsButton")

        # Canonical Address Button
        self.canonicalAddressesButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 150, 211, 30))
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setToolTip("Select to parse canonical address data")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setFont(font)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setObjectName("canonicalAddressesButton")

        # Main Window Label
        self.windowMainLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.windowMainLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 20, 423, 32))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.windowMainLabel.setFont(font)
        self.windowMainLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.windowMainLabel.setObjectName("windowMainLabel")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 291, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        # Combo Box settings
        self.ViewDataCB = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ViewDataCB.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 150, 231, 22))
        self.ViewDataCB.setToolTip("Choose data report type")
        self.ViewDataCB.setObjectName("ViewDataCB")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("canonical address")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("sim card")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("sms")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("call logs")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("choice prompt")
        self.ViewDataCB.addItem("full report")

        # # View Evidence Button
        self.viewReportsButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.viewReportsButton.setFont(font)
        self.viewReportsButton.setObjectName("viewReportsButton")



        # Label for evidence viewer
        self.evidenceViewingLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 120, 141, 16))
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setObjectName("evidenceViewingLabel")
        self.generateReportButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.generateReportButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 320, 141, 31))
        self.generateReportButton.setObjectName("generateReportButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.actionOpen_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_2.setObjectName("actionOpen_2")
        self.actionExit_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit_2.setObjectName("actionExit_2")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    # Function that sets the text on all the UI Buttons
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "SQLite DB Android Parser"))
        self.simCardButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sim Card"))
        self.callLogButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Call Logs"))
        self.smsButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SMS "))
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Canonical Addresses"))
        self.windowMainLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SQLite Android Database Parser"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Please Choose Data Parsing Option"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Choose An Option"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Canonical Address Report"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Sim Card Report"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "SMS Report"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Call Log Report"))
        self.ViewDataCB.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "Full Evidence Report"))
        self.viewReportsButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "View Reports"))
        self.viewReportsButton.setToolTip("Select to open report viewing window")
        self.evidenceViewingLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Report Generator"))
        self.generateReportButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Generate Report"))
        self.generateReportButton.setToolTip("Select to generate report")
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.actionOpen_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionExit_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))

    # Event Handling Code Section

        # Event Handling to open Report Viewer Window
        self.viewReportsButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 360, 141, 31))
        self.viewReportsButton.clicked.connect(self.openReportViewer)


        # Canonical Addresses Button click functionality to parse canonical address data
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.select_canonical_data)

    def select_canonical_data(self):
        os.system('CanonicalAddressesParser.py')



        # Call Logs Button click functionality to parse call log data
        self.callLogButton.clicked.connect(self.select_call_data)

    def select_call_data(self):
        os.system('CallLogParser.py')



        # SMS Button click functionality to parse SMS data
        self.smsButton.clicked.connect(self.select_sms_data)

    def select_sms_data(self):
        os.system('SmsParser.py')



        # Sim Card Button click functionality to parse sim card data
        self.simCardButton.clicked.connect(self.select_sim_data)

    def select_sim_data(self):
        os.system('SimCardParser.py')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: your buttons are working ? ...

Comment: Yes but lets say I run  
        self.smsButton.clicked.connect(self.select_sms_data)

    def select_sms_data(self):
        os.system('SmsParser.py')     It creates the data maybe 2 or 3 times as soon as I click it, instead of just creating it once.

Comment: I also cannot click any of these 4 buttons in any order. It seems the CanonicalAddresses button has to be clicked first before any others.

Comment: yes it must, I'll explain why

Comment: Yeah I tested it there, I moved one function above the other. The top function is the only one that works first it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't understand how is working connect.
What you did is :
1. connect the first button to a function when `retranslateUi` is called
2. the function called when you click on the button connects the next button to a new function
3. etc... for all button

So if you click several time in first button (let's say `canonicalAddressesButton`), it will connect several time the button `callLogButton`. So call several time the function `select_call_data`.

So to connect correctly all button you have to connect them ALL in the function `retranslateUi` and then declare your 4 function to connect after that.

Be aware of identation with python.

So you need to change that :

```
    # Canonical Addresses Button click functionality to parse canonical address data
    self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.select_canonical_data)

def select_canonical_data(self):
    os.system('CanonicalAddressesParser.py')

    # Call Logs Button click functionality to parse call log data
    self.callLogButton.clicked.connect(self.select_call_data)

def select_call_data(self):
    os.system('CallLogParser.py')

    # SMS Button click functionality to parse SMS data
    self.smsButton.clicked.connect(self.select_sms_data)

def select_sms_data(self):
    os.system('SmsParser.py')

    # Sim Card Button click functionality to parse sim card data
    self.simCardButton.clicked.connect(self.select_sim_data)

def select_sim_data(self):
    os.system('SimCardParser.py')
```

by :

```
    # Canonical Addresses Button click functionality to parse canonical address data
    self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.select_canonical_data)
    # Sim Card Button click functionality to parse sim card data
    self.simCardButton.clicked.connect(self.select_sim_data)
    # Call Logs Button click functionality to parse call log data
    self.callLogButton.clicked.connect(self.select_call_data)
    # SMS Button click functionality to parse SMS data
    self.smsButton.clicked.connect(self.select_sms_data)

def select_canonical_data(self):
    os.system('CanonicalAddressesParser.py')

def select_call_data(self):
    os.system('CallLogParser.py')

def select_sms_data(self):
    os.system('SmsParser.py')

def select_sim_data(self):
    os.system('SimCardParser.py')
```

Comment: Thank You I can see what I was doing wrong now. It works perfectly now. I will accept your answer.

Comment: great , glad it helps